# Can I get UAC prompt for user from batch file?

Tags: windows, permissions, batch, batch-file

Can I get UAC prompt for user from batch file?

For example I need put some keys to registry under *CurrentControlSet* from batch file by

```
  reg import path\to\my.reg
```

**PS**. **runas** is not a solution as my customers uses different Windows localisation and I can not guess which name used for Administrator account (this can be *Администратор*)...

And script don't know administrator password.

And UAC dialog box does not require password entering...

Comment: Have you tried the `runas` command?

Comment: I update answer in **PS** section...

Comment: In that case you may have to ship an application manifest with your batch file, e.g. such as in the "Requesting elevation" section of [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

Comment: From Wikipedia: *An assembly manifest is a text file containing metadata about .NET assemblies.* Bat file does not use manifest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I automatically generate **.js** and **.bat** files. From **.js**  call **.bat** so **.bat** can perform privileged actions (like adding values to registry as in example).

JS:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var curdir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName);

var objShell = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745.aspx
//                 Shell.ShellExecute method
// iRetVal = Shell.ShellExecute( sFile, [ vArguments ], [ vDirectory ], [ vOperation ], [ vShow ] )
objShell.ShellExecute("regimport.bat", curdir, "", "runas", 1);
```

BAT:

```
cd /d %1

reg import env_set.reg
pause
reg import env_del.reg
pause
```

**cd** is essential as bat file start execution from **%WINDIR%**...

Comment: You can see practical example of this technique at https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/utils/ci/tip/tree/win/uac

Comment: Is JS file guaranteed to execute on all version of Windows? I read that nodejs is required to run js files. What if the user does not have nodejs installed?

Comment: @AllSolutions Er... Windows comes with own JS interpreter since Win2000 ))) As a part of scripting engine. Nodejs have nothing to do with Windows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host

Comment: Does the Windows scripting engine support full JavaScript functionality?

Answer (score 3):

I really *love* [this solution from Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5969764/259953).

```
@if (1==1) @if(1==0) @ELSE
@echo off&SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"||(
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
    @goto :EOF
)
reg import path\to\my.reg
@goto :EOF
@end @ELSE
ShA=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")
ShA.ShellExecute("cmd.exe","/c \""+WScript.ScriptFullName+"\"","","runas",5);
@end
```

Should work flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut to reg.exe, give it the required arguments and set the "run as administrator" flag, then launch the shortcut from the batch file.

Comment: Finally I found solution. I can not create shortcut as script must perform action automatically...

Comment: @gavenkoa: why would using a shortcut prevent the script from performing the action automatically?

Comment: OK, I firstly don't get your idea... It is easy to put shortcut into `%TMP%` dir... +1